# ~85.5% of native code when profiling with Jet Brain's dotTrace?

Tags: windows-7, performance-testing, dottrace

Whenever I do a session (both samplig and timeline), it says like up to 70-80 percent of entire exuction is occupied by native code. It seems kind of suspicious, not quite sure whether I got a buggy environment (because due to objective restricitions I am working on a damn Windows 7) or it's actually fine?

[image: Screenshot:]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a normal situation in case of profiling a web application hosted on IIS as IIS is a native application itself. So if all of your app's methods are presented in a snaphot then you have nothing to worry about.

See this page for details: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/profiler/Profile_ASP_Web_Site.html

> "Note that it is normal that the snapshots contain large amount of
> native code"

Comment: It's WPF desktop.

Comment: Well, it is a kind of normal situation for WPF apps too. There should be less native code in Sampling profiling mode, but it depends on the profiled app.