# High CPU Usage in in Native code

Tags: profiling, cpu-usage, azure-webjobs

I have a .net C# Azure WebJob Project that runs on a Queue Trigger, it does parallel background processing,
I am having excessive CPU usage.
I have used Resharper's Performance Profiler and CPU consumption Breaks up like this:

[image]

[image]

75% of CPU time is in "Native Stack traces without resolved functions"

Less than 10% of CPU time is in actual User code.

How can i found what is the real cause of high CPU consumption?

Web job have this parameters / Settings:

```
QueueBatchSize = 8
NewBatchThreshold = 4
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = Int32.MaxValue
ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(250, 250)
```

Framework 4.7, all nuget reference using last versions.

Any Ideas how to diagnose this?

Comment: what is the app service plan that you are using ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [~85.5% of native code when profiling with Jet Brain's dotTrace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50228854/85-5-of-native-code-when-profiling-with-jet-brains-dottrace)