# Asp.net MVC performance profiling results showing 97% of bottlenecks in code "without resolved functions"

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, performance

I am trying to profile a moderately complex asp.net mvc web app with SQL Server backend. I'm seeing the same issue using both Ants Performance Profiler and dotTract Profiler. Both basically state that over 97% of the processing is occurring in "Native stack traces without resolved functions"

We've done a load test on the app and I know that the part of workflow I used to run profile test has performance issues - it doesn't scale well and has errors at a fairly low load. I was hoping the profiling would allow me to see the specific methods causing performance issues, but there seems to maybe be something else going on.

Any idea if maybe something else is going on here not directly related to my code?
[image]
[image]

Comment: What version of dotTrace are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [~85.5% of native code when profiling with Jet Brain's dotTrace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50228854/85-5-of-native-code-when-profiling-with-jet-brains-dottrace)

Comment: @mjwills I'm using 2018.3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [High CPU Usage in in Native code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50762340/high-cpu-usage-in-in-native-code)